# T-SQL Cursor + Dynamic SQL (Number of rows that reference a specific primary key)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've to count how many times a key is being used across tables. I have the following code that gets all the tables that reference the key:

```
SELECT s.SCHEMA_NAME,
    OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
    COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc
        ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT i.SCHEMA_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA i
            INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES s
                ON i.SCHEMA_NAME = SCHEMA_NAME(s.SCHEMA_ID)
        WHERE f.parent_object_id = s.object_id
    ) AS s
WHERE OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) = 'Languages'
```

Result:

[SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziuDP.png)

And this is the query I have to do for each returned row, and finally SUM all of them:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SchemaName.TableName t
WHERE t.ColumnName = @LanguageId
```

I've been reading about CURSORs and dynamic SQL but I couldn't manage a way to make it work (never used any of them).

The use of cursors / dynamic SQL is not a requirement. If there are simpler ways I appreciate.

EDIT: I managed to make it work.
EDIT2: Some refactoring and full implementation of the actual requirement.

```
DECLARE @WantedDefaultLanguageId INT = 1;

--Internal Variables
DECLARE @DefaultLanguageId INT = (SELECT Id FROM i18n.Languages WHERE IsDefault = 1)
    , @SqlCommand NVARCHAR(1000)
    , @SchemaName SYSNAME
    , @TableName SYSNAME
    , @FieldName SYSNAME
    , @CurrentValue INT
    , @DefaultTotal INT = 0
    , @WantedTotal INT = 0;

DECLARE relationships CURSOR
    LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY 
    FOR SELECT schemaNames.SCHEMA_NAME,
            OBJECT_NAME(foreignKeys.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
            COL_NAME(foreignKeysColumns.parent_object_id, foreignKeysColumns.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName
        FROM sys.foreign_keys AS foreignKeys
            INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS foreignKeysColumns
                ON foreignKeys.OBJECT_ID = foreignKeysColumns.constraint_object_id
            OUTER APPLY
            (
                SELECT metadata.SCHEMA_NAME
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA metadata
                    INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES AS sysTables
                        ON metadata.SCHEMA_NAME = SCHEMA_NAME(sysTables.SCHEMA_ID)
                WHERE foreignKeys.parent_object_id = sysTables.object_id
            ) AS schemaNames
        WHERE OBJECT_NAME (foreignKeys.referenced_object_id) = 'Languages';

IF @DefaultLanguageId = @WantedDefaultLanguageId
    SELECT 1;
ELSE
    BEGIN
        OPEN relationships
            FETCH NEXT FROM relationships
            INTO @SchemaName, @TableName, @FieldName; 

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
            BEGIN   
                SET @SqlCommand = '
                    SELECT @CurrentValue = COUNT(*)
                    FROM ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ' tableName
                    WHERE tableName.' + @FieldName + ' = ' + CAST(@DefaultLanguageId AS nvarchar(1000))

                EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCommand, N'@CurrentValue INT OUTPUT', @CurrentValue OUTPUT

                SET @DefaultTotal += @CurrentValue

                --■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■

                SET @SqlCommand = '
                    SELECT @CurrentValue = COUNT(*)
                    FROM ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ' tableName
                    WHERE tableName.' + @FieldName + ' = ' + CAST(@WantedDefaultLanguageId AS nvarchar(1000))

                EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCommand, N'@CurrentValue INT OUTPUT', @CurrentValue OUTPUT

                SET @WantedTotal += @CurrentValue

                --■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■

                FETCH NEXT FROM relationships
                INTO @SchemaName, @TableName, @FieldName; 
            END 

        CLOSE relationships
        DEALLOCATE relationships

        SELECT CASE 
            WHEN @WantedTotal = @DefaultTotal THEN
                1
            ELSE 0
        END
    END;
```

It's taking a very long time to run. This query won't be ran very often but any help to improve it / better ways to implement this functionality is appreciated.
(I'll close the question later on).

Edit3: Ok so here is a example of what I need:

```
Table: Language
Id     Language
1      English

RelationalTable1
... LanguageId
    1
    1
    2

AllOtherRelationalTables
...
```

I need to do a COUNT of how many times the LanguageId = 1 (for all tables that reference the Language Table). The code is working, but would like to know if there is a simpler way of implementing this / improving it.

Comment: It helps if you tag you question with the database software you are using, e.g. `sql-server`. `tsql` doesn't quite pin it down.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you actually want here. Do you just want a list of all the Foreign Key references, or do you want to search the DB for all tables where a given key value is being used?

Comment: Additionally, you can declare SchemaName, TableName, and FieldName as "sysname" and not nvarchar(4000). All schema names in SQLServer are of type sysname (which is nvarchar(128) if you're curious). And you should declare CURSORS as "FAST_FORWARD" whenever you can. Also, your SQL doesn't seem to deal with compound primary keys.

Comment: @pmbAustin thanks for the tips, changed it and it seems the query is running very fast now. And yes I want to COUNT how many times a key is referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the post works, probably not the best solution but does the job.

```
DECLARE @WantedDefaultLanguageId INT = 1;

--Internal Variables
DECLARE @DefaultLanguageId INT = (SELECT Id FROM i18n.Languages WHERE IsDefault = 1)
    , @SqlCommand NVARCHAR(1000)
    , @SchemaName SYSNAME
    , @TableName SYSNAME
    , @FieldName SYSNAME
    , @CurrentValue INT
    , @DefaultTotal INT = 0
    , @WantedTotal INT = 0;

DECLARE relationships CURSOR
    LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY 
    FOR SELECT schemaNames.SCHEMA_NAME,
            OBJECT_NAME(foreignKeys.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
            COL_NAME(foreignKeysColumns.parent_object_id, foreignKeysColumns.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName
        FROM sys.foreign_keys AS foreignKeys
            INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS foreignKeysColumns
                ON foreignKeys.OBJECT_ID = foreignKeysColumns.constraint_object_id
            OUTER APPLY
            (
                SELECT metadata.SCHEMA_NAME
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA metadata
                    INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES AS sysTables
                        ON metadata.SCHEMA_NAME = SCHEMA_NAME(sysTables.SCHEMA_ID)
                WHERE foreignKeys.parent_object_id = sysTables.object_id
            ) AS schemaNames
        WHERE OBJECT_NAME (foreignKeys.referenced_object_id) = 'Languages';

IF @DefaultLanguageId = @WantedDefaultLanguageId
    SELECT 1;
ELSE
    BEGIN
        OPEN relationships
            FETCH NEXT FROM relationships
            INTO @SchemaName, @TableName, @FieldName; 

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
            BEGIN   
                SET @SqlCommand = '
                    SELECT @CurrentValue = COUNT(*)
                    FROM ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ' tableName
                    WHERE tableName.' + @FieldName + ' = ' + CAST(@DefaultLanguageId AS nvarchar(1000))

                EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCommand, N'@CurrentValue INT OUTPUT', @CurrentValue OUTPUT

                SET @DefaultTotal += @CurrentValue

                --■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■

                SET @SqlCommand = '
                    SELECT @CurrentValue = COUNT(*)
                    FROM ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ' tableName
                    WHERE tableName.' + @FieldName + ' = ' + CAST(@WantedDefaultLanguageId AS nvarchar(1000))

                EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCommand, N'@CurrentValue INT OUTPUT', @CurrentValue OUTPUT

                SET @WantedTotal += @CurrentValue

                --■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■

                FETCH NEXT FROM relationships
                INTO @SchemaName, @TableName, @FieldName; 
            END 

        CLOSE relationships
        DEALLOCATE relationships

        SELECT CASE 
            WHEN @WantedTotal = @DefaultTotal THEN
                1
            ELSE 0
        END
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what precisely you're asking for, but this MAY help you...

This SQL will get you all the FK column information:

```
SELECT fkeys.[name] AS FKName, 
        OBJECT_NAME(fkeys.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
        (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + c.[name]
         FROM sys.foreign_keys fk INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
              INNER JOIN sys.columns as c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
              INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON c.column_id = fc.parent_column_id 
                                                      AND fc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id 
                                                      AND fc.parent_object_id = fk.parent_object_id 
        WHERE fk.[name] = fkeys.[name]
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')) AS FKFolumns,
        OBJECT_NAME(fkeys.referenced_object_id) AS ReferencedTableName,
        (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + c.[name]
         FROM sys.foreign_keys fk INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON fk.referenced_object_id = t.object_id
              INNER JOIN sys.columns as c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
              INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON c.column_id = fc.referenced_column_id 
                                                      AND fc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id 
                                                      AND fc.referenced_object_id = fk.referenced_object_id 
        WHERE fk.[name] = fkeys.[name]
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')) AS ReferencedFKColumns
   FROM sys.foreign_keys fkeys
```

You can use this to extract the count of things that reference a given table and column:

```
WITH AllFKInfo AS (
    SELECT fkeys.[name] AS FKName, 
            OBJECT_NAME(fkeys.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
            (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + c.[name]
             FROM sys.foreign_keys fk INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
                  INNER JOIN sys.columns as c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                  INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON c.column_id = fc.parent_column_id 
                                                          AND fc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id 
                                                          AND fc.parent_object_id = fk.parent_object_id 
            WHERE fk.[name] = fkeys.[name]
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')) AS FKFolumns,
            OBJECT_NAME(fkeys.referenced_object_id) AS ReferencedTableName,
            (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + c.[name]
             FROM sys.foreign_keys fk INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON fk.referenced_object_id = t.object_id
                  INNER JOIN sys.columns as c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                  INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON c.column_id = fc.referenced_column_id 
                                                          AND fc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id 
                                                          AND fc.referenced_object_id = fk.referenced_object_id 
            WHERE fk.[name] = fkeys.[name]
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')) AS ReferencedFKColumns
       FROM sys.foreign_keys fkeys
)
SELECT ReferencedTableName, ReferencedFKColumns, COUNT(ReferencedFKColumns) AS CountOfReferences
FROM AllFKInfo
GROUP BY ReferencedTableName, ReferencedFKColumns
ORDER BY ReferencedTableName, ReferencedFKColumns
```

Comment: Based on the table names and the post itself I think he wants to know how many translations have been made for a certain language. So he gets all tables that are related to the Language table and then need to do a COUNT in those tables for a specific language id. And based on the variable names the point is to know if the user can change the default language (and the requirement is to have 100% of the translations done, that's why comparing the total amount of the current default with the wanted one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need what LoadIt explained (i'll edit the main post to explain better). But basically I need to know for a specific language lets say "Id: 1 Language: English" I need to first know all tables that reference a key from the table Languages and then do a COUNT of the references for the LanguageId1